# remove duplicate values in cell without removing row

Tags: r

I have a column of strings variables that are separated with white space and need to remain strings. How can I remove the duplicate values and values longer than 4 characters?

```
company        counts 
company1       2222 2222 45345234 425352352352 6574745 299
company2       9909 4363465246 543 323 9909 3454534534 768
```

I would like to end up with something like this:

```
company        counts 
company1       2222 299
company2       9909 543 323 768
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strsplit` the strings, remove the long ones and the duplicates and `paste` back together:

```
sapply(
    strsplit(dat$counts, "\\s+"),
    \(x) paste(x[nchar(x) <= 4 & (!duplicated(x))], collapse=" ")
)
##[1] "2222 299"         "9909 543 323 768"
```

Where `dat` was:

```
dat <- read.csv(text="company,counts 
company1,2222 2222 45345234 425352352352 6574745 299
company2,9909 4363465246 543 323 9909 3454534534 768")
```

Answer (score 2):

`gsub` could be ued to remove longer strings and duplicated.

```
gsub("\\b[^ ]{5,}\\b *", "", dat$counts) |>                #Remove longer than 4
gsub("\\b([^ ]+)\\b (?=.*\\b\\1\\b)", "", x=_, perl=TRUE) #Remove duplicated
#[1] "2222 299"         "543 323 9909 768"
```